# How can I query numbers by how large they are in Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm making a website with Flask and i'd like to show the most recent posts. I have timestamps attached to each post (unix epoch) so i'd just need how to query by how large a number is. Here's my code if you need it:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
if request.method == "POST":
    postToBoard(1, request.form["content"], request.form["post_name"])
if "user" in session:
    user = session["user"]
home_posts = posts.query.filter_by(board=1).paginate(1, 25, error_out=False)
if "user" in session:
    return render_template("index.html", all_posts=home_posts, header=f"Welcome back, {user}.", values=home_posts, name=website_name)
else:
    return render_template("index.html", all_posts=home_posts, header=f"Welcome to {website_name}.", values=home_posts, name=website_name)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.